# How to retrieve the specific indexes from array?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have this array :

```
 Point[] arr  = samples.pointsArray;
```

I using this row to retrieve all elements that satisfy condition:

```
var maxXCol = arr.Where( p => maxX.X == p.X );
```

Any idea how to modify row above, to get only the indexes of these elements?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

Use the version of `Select` that takes both the index and the object and create an anonymous object with the object and index inside it.  It would look like this:

```
someEnumerable.Select((obj, idx) => new {Item = obj, Index = idx})
```

You'll need to do this *before* you use `Where` so that the original index remains intact after the filter operation.

In the following operations you can use the item like so:

```
x => x.Item
```

and the index like so:

```
x => x.Index
```

Comment: Note to downvoters: both Honza's and my answer were enough information to correctly solve the problem, but contained minor (easy to fix on your own) errors.  Next time use a *comment* to indicate this!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Select` overload which takes an index, and project that index together with the original row. Then take only the index for the result collection.

```
var maxXCol = arr
    .Select((p, index) => new { Item = p, Index = index })
    .Where(p => maxX.X == p.Item.X)
    .Select(x => x.Index);
```

Comment: Well, at least I can fix your unfortunate loss of points...GL next time...That'll teach us to post a useful answer with minor mistakes! ;)

Comment: Thanks, did the same for you. Yup, we should proofread better next time before posting :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var maxXCol = arr.Select((p, inx) => new { p,inx})
                 .Where(y => maxX.X == y.p.X)
                 .Select(z => z.inx);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may select the value first with the index in anonymous type, later you filter it with your condition and then select the index.

```
var result = arr.Select((g, index) => new { g, index })
              .Where(r => maxX.X == r.X)
              .Select(t => t.index);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
arr.Select((e,i)=>new{index=i, value=e}).Where(ei=>ei.value.X==maxX.X).Select(ei=>ei.index);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var maxXCol = arr
    .Select((a, b) => new { b, a })
    .Where(p => maxX.X == p.a.X)
    .Select(i=>i.b);
```